Install Python package (jpeg2dct)
I couldn't solve it any other way, so I installed Linux and use the libraries there. 

I would like to install this Python package, but I am having trouble.
I don’t really understand what I’m doing exactly, and I would like to ask for help with this!
I will send the initial situation (I currently have Python 3.11 installed, and TensorFlow is installed, but when using pip install jpeg2dct from the command line, it throws these errors).
C:\Users\Peti>pip install jpeg2dct
Collecting jpeg2dct
  Using cached jpeg2dct-0.2.4.tar.gz (106 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\peti\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from jpeg2dct) (1.26.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: jpeg2dct
  Building wheel for jpeg2dct (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [190 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\jpeg2dct
      copying jpeg2dct\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\jpeg2dct
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\test
      copying test\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\test
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\jpeg2dct\common
      copying jpeg2dct\common\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\jpeg2dct\common
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\jpeg2dct\numpy
      copying jpeg2dct\numpy\dctfromjpg_wrapper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\jpeg2dct\numpy
      copying jpeg2dct\numpy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\jpeg2dct\numpy
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\jpeg2dct\petastorm
      copying jpeg2dct\petastorm\codecs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\jpeg2dct\petastorm
      copying jpeg2dct\petastorm\ex.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\jpeg2dct\petastorm
      copying jpeg2dct\petastorm\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\jpeg2dct\petastorm
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\jpeg2dct\tensorflow
      copying jpeg2dct\tensorflow\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\jpeg2dct\tensorflow
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\test\numpy
      copying test\numpy\test_load.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\test\numpy
      copying test\numpy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\test\numpy
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\test\tensorflow
      copying test\tensorflow\test_decode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\test\tensorflow
      copying test\tensorflow\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\test\tensorflow
      running build_ext
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" -std=c++11 -fPIC -O2 /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tpbuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\test_compile\test_cpp_flags.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\test_compile\test_cpp_flags.obj
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++11'
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fPIC'
      test_cpp_flags.cc
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe" /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22621.0\\um\x64" build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\test_compile\test_cpp_flags.obj /OUT:build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\test_compile\test_cpp_flags.dll
      Generating code
      Finished generating code
      2024-11-05 12:50:40.684362: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:153] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
      2024-11-05 12:50:41.745552: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:153] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
      building 'jpeg2dct.tensorflow.tf_lib' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\jpeg2dct
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\jpeg2dct\tensorflow
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I.\include -IC:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tpjpeg2dct/tensorflow/tf_lib.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\jpeg2dct/tensorflow/tf_lib.obj -std=c++11 -fPIC -O2 /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\include -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 --std=c++17 -DEIGEN_MAX_ALIGN_BYTES=64
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++11'
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fPIC'
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '--std=c++17'
      tf_lib.cc
      C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\include\ml_dtypes/include/float8.h(490): error C7525: inline variables require at least '/std:c++17'

(many more lines like this)


 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include\optional(11): warning STL4038: The contents of <optional> are available only with C++17 or later.
  C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\include\ml_dtypes/include/intn.h(88): error C2833: 'operator optional' is not a recognized operator or type
  C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\include\ml_dtypes/include/intn.h(88): note: the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
  C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\include\ml_dtypes/include/intn.h(32): note: while compiling class template 'ml_dtypes::intN'
  C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\include\ml_dtypes/include/intn.h(88): error C2059: syntax error: 'newline'
  C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\include\ml_dtypes/include/intn.h(88): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
  C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\include\ml_dtypes/include/intn.h(253): error C7525: inline variables require at least '/std:c++17'
  C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\include\ml_dtypes/include/intn.h(253): note: the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
  C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\include\ml_dtypes/include/intn.h(252): note: while compiling class template 'ml_dtypes::internal::intN_numeric_limits_base'
  C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\include\ml_dtypes/include/intn.h(253): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
  INFO: Unable to build TensorFlow plugin, will skip it.

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 421, in compile
      self.spawn(args)
    File "C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 521, in spawn
      return super().spawn(cmd, env=env)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1007, in spawn
      spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\spawn.py", line 70, in spawn
      raise DistutilsExecError(
  distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.41.34120\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fh69s9it\jpeg2dct_6e7d8c69e743433bb9c3a92508f39070\setup.py", line 270, in build_extensions
      abi_compile_flags = build_tf_extension(self, options)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fh69s9it\jpeg2dct_6e7d8c69e743433bb9c3a92508f39070\setup.py", line 255, in build_tf_extension
      build_ext.build_extension(tf_lib)
    File "C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 246, in build_extension
      _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    File "C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 547, in build_extension
      objects = self.compiler.compile(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 423, in compile
      raise CompileError(msg)
  distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.41.34120\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

  building 'jpeg2dct.common.common_lib' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\jpeg2dct\common
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I.\include -IC:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tpjpeg2dct/common/dctfromjpg.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\jpeg2dct/common/dctfromjpg.obj -std=c++11 -fPIC -O2 /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++11'
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fPIC'
  dctfromjpg.cc
  jpeg2dct/common/dctfromjpg.cc(16): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'jpeglib.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.41.34120\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for jpeg2dct
  Running setup.py clean for jpeg2dct
Failed to build jpeg2dct
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (jpeg2dct)

I have tried several things that were suggested (I downloaded the VS C++ compiler, I downloaded TensorFlow because it requested it, I installed Python 3.11 because it had issues with that version, and I downloaded jpeg2dct.tar.gz and set the jpeglib.h in setup.py), but even after these steps, it still throws errors during installation (when using pip install jpeg2dct).
UPDATE:
I followed these steps, but the result is still the same (if I did something that doesn’t make sense, please let me know):

Downloaded MinGW and added it to the PATH (C:\MinGW\bin)

Created a distutils.cfg file in C:\Python11\Lib\distutils with the following content:
[build]
compiler=mingw32

[build_ext]
compiler=mingw32


Downloaded MSYS2 and installed the pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-libjpeg-turbo package

Updated the config file with additional paths:
[build]
compiler=mingw32

[build_ext]
compiler=mingw32
include_dirs=C:\msys64\mingw64\include
library_dirs=C:\msys64\mingw64\lib



The new error:
Collecting jpeg2dct
  Using cached jpeg2dct-0.2.4.tar.gz (106 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [48 lines of output]
      Collecting numpy
        Using cached numpy-2.1.3.tar.gz (20.2 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [23 lines of output]
        + C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hwdaewk_\numpy_9afa6fe059f44d0997baec302991a89c\vendored-meson\meson\meson.py setup C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hwdaewk_\numpy_9afa6fe059f44d0997baec302991a89c C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hwdaewk_\numpy_9afa6fe059f44d0997baec302991a89c\.mesonpy-5peha7pq -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hwdaewk_\numpy_9afa6fe059f44d0997baec302991a89c\.mesonpy-5peha7pq\meson-python-native-file.ini
        The Meson build system
        Version: 1.5.2
        Source dir: C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hwdaewk_\numpy_9afa6fe059f44d0997baec302991a89c
        Build dir: C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hwdaewk_\numpy_9afa6fe059f44d0997baec302991a89c\.mesonpy-5peha7pq
        Build type: native build
        Project name: NumPy
        Project version: 2.1.3
        C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 14.2.0 "cc (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 14.2.0")
        C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.43.1

        ..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unable to get gcc pre-processor defines:
        Compiler stdout:

        -----
        Compiler stderr:
        c++: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1': CreateProcess: No such file or directory
        compilation terminated.

        -----


        A full log can be found at C:\Users\Peti\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hwdaewk_\numpy_9afa6fe059f44d0997baec302991a89c\.mesonpy-5peha7pq\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed

      Encountered error while generating package metadata.

      See above for output.

      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for details.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


add the error in questions also

Okay, sorry for this, I fixed it, I pasted the terminal content.

The error messages "ignoring unknown option '-std=c++11'", "'-fPIC'", "'--std=c++17'" and the code in setup.py suggest the library is intended to be compiled with gcc. The code hints it's either MacOS or Linux. Try WSL2, may be MINGW64/MSYS2, but not pure Windows.

I updated the question after my attempts, but unfortunately, the issue remains the same.

"…the error is still the same…" That means you still use VSC which shouldn't work. Try python -m pip install where python is from MINGW.

I tried what you told me (if I did it correctly): C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python -m pip install jpeg2dct, but it wasn't successful, now it's complaining about something else.

Compiler cc from gcc cannot find its part cc1. Is gcc properly installed? cc1 is not in PATH, it's in gcc directories.

"I found the cc1 file in a different folder C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\14.2.0 and added it to the path. The erros message is still tha same.

Problem caused by "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'jpeglib.h': No such file or directory". Please try install 'libjpeg-dev'.
